# Database Backup not working in codeignator using pdo

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter, pdo

I'm getting the below error while using the below database backup code in codeigniter pdo driver :

```
$this->load->dbutil();
$prefs = array(
    'format' => 'zip', // gzip, zip, txt
    'filename' => 'backup_' . date('m_d_Y_H_i_s') . '.sql', // File name - NEEDED ONLY WITH ZIP FILES
    'add_drop' => TRUE, // Whether to add DROP TABLE statements to backup file
    'add_insert' => TRUE, // Whether to add INSERT data to backup file
    'newline' => "\n"               // Newline character used in backup file
);
$backup = $this->dbutil->backup($prefs);

$this->load->helper('file');
write_file('/path/to/' . 'dbbackup_' . date('m_d_Y_H_i_s') . '.zip', $backup);
$this->load->helper('download');
force_download('dbbackup_' . date('m_d_Y_H_i_s') . '.zip', $backup);
```

> Unsupported feature of the database platform you are using.
>
> Filename: E:/xampp/htdocs/pvr/system/database/drivers/pdo/pdo_utility.php
>
> Line Number: 60

In mysqli server using this code I'm getting the database backup but in pdo getting this error so please help me to get database backup in pdo driver

Comment: _"while using database backup code"_ - What code? Please show us the code that causes this error and you might also want to include what database you're using (since that seems to be directly relevant to the error message)? Please read: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Please tell me CI version?

Comment: 3.1.10 my CI version

Comment: You still haven't told us what database platform you are using. As it says [in the manual about `dbutil->backup()`](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/utilities.html#backup-your-database), _"This feature is only available for MySQL and Interbase/Firebird databases"_

Comment: Im using pdo for it

Comment: PDO is the _library/driver_ you're using to communicate with the database platform, which can be MySQL, MariaDB, Postgres, MSSQL, SQLite etc.

Comment: MySQL im using through phpMyadmin

Answer (score 1):

1. Confirm pdo of mysql  enabled in php ini
2. properly check code from 
   https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/utilities.html?

https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/configuration.html?

3. try this code it 100% working

controller/DATABASE_BACKUP.php

```
<?php
    class DATABASE_BACKUP extends CI_Controller {

        public function index()
        {
            $this->load->database();

            // Load the DB utility class
            $this->load->dbutil();

            // Backup your entire database and assign it to a variable
            $backup = $this->dbutil->backup();

            // Load the file helper and write the file to your server
            $this->load->helper('file');
            write_file('mybackup.gz', $backup);

            // Load the download helper and send the file to your desktop
            $this->load->helper('download');
            //force_download('mybackup.gz', $backup);
        }
    }
?>
```

my database configuration
config/database.php

```
<?php
    $active_group = 'default';
    $query_builder = TRUE;

    $db['default'] = array(
        'dsn'   => '',
        'hostname' => 'localhost',
        'username' => 'root',
        'password' => '',
        'database' => 'faker_db',
        'dbdriver' => 'mysqli',
        'dbprefix' => '',
        'pconnect' => FALSE,
        'db_debug' => (ENVIRONMENT !== 'production'),
        'cache_on' => FALSE,
        'cachedir' => '',
        'char_set' => 'utf8',
        'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
        'swap_pre' => '',
        'encrypt' => FALSE,
        'compress' => FALSE,
        'stricton' => FALSE,
        'failover' => array(),
        'save_queries' => TRUE 
    );
?>
```

Comment: Please provide proper attribution for the code you copied.

Comment: i can download database backup in mysqli but i want it in pdo